# Is it right to place a big 42mb json data file in repository, which is getting used by jmeter performance test suite?

Tags: java, json, jmeter

In my project I have a sub-project in which jmeter performance related files are present. Now our requirement is to execute that suite with large data set. We are using json data sets here, so we have placed the json file in same directory where this jmeter jmx file is present. 
My concern is whether this is the right approach to place test data along with repository or not. This will increase the repository size unwantedly. 
Please suggest what other best ways I can use to solve this problem?

Comment: Why wouldn't you use a database?

Comment: Thanks for the Response. Actually , we need to place this file along with the jmeter jmx file for performance testing.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of compressing a file with i.e. [Zip archiver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format)). You will be able to  unpack it during the test run using [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and the following [Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) code:

```
def myZippedJson = new java.util.zip.ZipFile(new File('foo.zip'))

myZippedJson.entries().each {
   def unpackedJson = myZippedJson.getInputStream(it).text
   // do what you need with the data, i.e. store it into ${JSON} property like:
   props.put('JSON', unpackedJson)
}
```

It's better to put this sampler inside [setUp Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#setUp_Thread_Group) so it would be executed only once

See [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article for more information on using scripting in JMeter tests.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Dmitri , I can't use groovy here because it will make it heavy . we are already using python script to trigger this jmeter test so if possible to achieve something related to my requirement using python please suggest ?

Comment: According to your solution i can place json file in zipped format in my repository and later can jmeter will be able to read that zipped json ?